# Load CCBi files in Cocos Creator

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, spritebuilder, cocosbuilder, cocoscreator

I am a game developer and Develop Games using cocos2dx, I have just started to move on cocos creator for game development.I have used cocosbuilder binary animation files with cocos2dx but I am not able to use it with cocos creator as there is not enough documentation of it on official website of cocos creator. Please let me know how to use published cocos builder files in cocos creator. I don't have project files so I can not import ccbi project directly in cocos creator, it was generated by a freelancer and i can not have project files. I just need to load the ccbi animation directly in cocos creator. Please help me.